# How to calculate the solubility for the hydrogen concentration based on the pressure and temperature in the Metal Hydride Hydrogen compressors?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility, hydrogen

My name is Ketan Karkare and I am a student in the University. I am currently working on the metal hydride compression and have gone through the following paper: Mathematical modeling for the PCT curve and have DOI uploaded below:

DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/0360-3199(94)90097-3

I was trying to work on the derivation for the hydrogen composition based on pressure and temperature which is the equation (1) and also given below:

$C_{H}=AP^{\gamma/2}\exp{\frac{-\gamma V_{H} P}{RT}}\exp{\frac{\Delta H_{s}}{RT}}$...… (1)

Can someone please explain the derivation or share the document which has the derivation for this formula

Comment: The paper cites "Z. Q. Zhou, F. Feng, J. L. Zhang and J. S. Ge, *Proc. Syrup. on Hydrogen Storage Materials and their Applications*, p. 139. Tianjin, China" as the source for the equation. I'm afraid you might need to find the original text. As for the question, I'd suggest to include definitions for all non-standard variables (just don't post screenshot from a paper, please).

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems the exponential functions might have been derived from the Van't Hoff integrated equation: $ln(P)=\frac{\Delta H}{RT}-\frac{\Delta S}{R}$

Comment: Hello Everyone! Thank you for your reply , @andselik I am trying to find the following book as you stated but not able to get the original book as well.